# Notify when Application uninstall from Android Device

Tags: android

I want to create an **Application** such that if it is uninstalled by user then I want to stop uninstallation of **Application**.

How I can do this ?

Thanks

Comment: lol @Kartik Bhatt, with you other question, it looks like you virus is gonna be harsh on android users. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why? why? why? As a user, if I want to uninstall an app, then I no longer want it, and it should be uninstalled if I am uninstalling it. It should also not be reinstalled unless I exclusively do so.

But there are some applications which we cannot uninstall unless we have a rooted device. Those are the apps like market, Google maps, camera etc which are installed by the manufacturers. You would want to create an app which is so good and useful and then convince the manufacturers or service providers to preinstall the app and prevent the users from uninstalling it. Examples : Swype, Skype, Facebook, Twitter etc

But if the app is a normal app then I would recommend against such a thing.

For your question, you cannot do so unless you are the manufacturer.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. There is no such event in Android. Also you can't stop uninstallation of your or any other app. For this you'll need some permissions that are only granted to system applications.